# Unwrap enum variant and return either owned value or reference

Tags: rust, enums, borrow-checker

Suppose I have an enum with two variants, each of which wraps around a single value of a different type - and the enum is generic on these two types:

```
enum AorB<A, B> {
    A(A),
    B(B),
}
```

It frequently happens in my codebase that I know which variant I am receiving and I need to unwrap the inner value of the known type. I know this could raise some questions about the design, but let us put those aside. In any case, I would like to write convenience unwrapping methods in order to avoid having to `match` every time that situation arises.

That situation essentially takes two forms: I have a pointer to an `AorB<A, B>` and I want to get a pointer to the inner value; or when I am happy to consume the full `AorB<A, B>` object and want to get ownership of the inner value. This gives rise to four methods:

```
impl<A, B> AorB<A, B> {
    fn unwrap_a(self) -> A {
        match self {
            AorB::A(a) => a,
            _ => panic!(),
        }
    }

    fn unwrap_b(self) -> B {
        match self {
            AorB::B(b) => b,
            _ => panic!(),
        }
    }

    fn unwrap_a_ref(&self) -> &A {
        match self {
            AorB::A(a) => a,
            _ => panic!(),
        }
    }

    fn unwrap_b_ref(&self) -> &B {
        match self {
            AorB::B(b) => b,
            _ => panic!(),
        }
    }
}
```

**My question is**: is there a way to simplify these into four methods into two (one for each variant) and automatically handle the owned vs. reference cases elegantly?

Here are my current thoughts:

1. I know there are traits such as `AsRef` and `Borrow` which are meant to flexibly handle various ownership situations, but I cannot see how to directly apply them to the aforementioned methods.
2. A more or less obvious solution is to only leave the `_ref` methods in, and simply have the caller `clone()` the output whenever ownership is needed. I think if one then replaces `e.unwrap_a()` by `e.unwrap_a_ref().clone()`, `e` will be automatically deallocated by the borrow checker after the call as it is not used afterwards (otherwise `e.unwrap_a()` would not compile), so that memory usage is basically not duplicated by the switch to the `_ref` method. Is this correct? In any case, the call to `clone()` is slightly inconvenient on the caller side, and it does involve copying data in a way that `unwrap_a` did not need.
3. A third option would be to only leave `_ref` methods in and add `A: Deref` and `B: Deref` in the `AorB` definition. This is very similar to 2, only the caller is spared the call to `clone()` (as far as I can tell). The slight issue with this approach is that `A` and `B` will be my own types in practice, and I would rather avoid implementing `Deref` for them if possible, as this can be a delicate trait.

Is there a better way than 2 or 3 above to achieve the method simplification I am seeking?

Comment: Avoid 3, in general don't implement `Deref`, there's a [note in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html). An alternative suggestion, use `A` and `B` directly, and only use `AorB` at a higher level when it makes sense. But functions that specifically operate on `A` should receive `A`/`&A`. Such that the caller is responsible for asserting that `AorB` is an `A`

Comment: Why do you want to abstract over "borrowedness" of a value? Rust isn't really flexible to do such things. Can you show us your use-case? Why can't you just call separate functions in given context. I guess that at the call site you know if you want/can to use an owned value, or a reference. Do you simply want to reduce code duplication?

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze indeed, the only reason is to avoid having four separate functions for two "semantic" functionalities: the cases A and B. I do agree with your take that Rust is precisely designed to be strict with these kinds of things, but I still wanted to ask in case there is a clean way to handle it.

Comment: @vallentin Indeed, I had seen that note and that's caused my misgivings (at the end of point 3). Thanks for pointing it out though, one can never be careful enough.

Comment: @AMG When you mention needing 4 separate functions, are you referring to your `unwrap` methods, or are you referring to functions operating on `AorB`, `A`, and `B`. Because if you have as an example `enum TypedPath { File(PathBuf), Dir(PathBuf) }`, and you often need to `unwrap` as you say. Then it might make more sense to have `enum PathKind { File, Dir }` and `struct TypedPath(PathKind, PathBuf)`. Then you'd be able to obtain the data (in this case path), without needing to match the kind

Comment: I was indeed referring to the four methods, thank you. The issue I see with your proposed solution is that the wrapped types `A` and `B` in my `enum` are not the same - as opposed to your example, where both variants wrap around a `PathBuf`, which can therefore always be pulled out as a field of a new type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Option` has a similar problem, it solves it by introducing a method `as_ref` which allows going from `&Option<T>` to `Option<&T>` I think it works here quite well, too:

```rust
impl<A, B> AorB<A, B> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> AorB<&A, &B> {
        match self {
            AorB::A(a) => AorB::A(a),
            AorB::B(b) => AorB::B(b),
        }
    }
}
```

then whenever you need to avoid consuming you just insert a call to `as_ref`:

```rust
a_or_b.as_ref().unwrap_a();
```

instead of calling `.unwrap_a()` directly.

Comment: Thank you, I did go for (a tailored version of) this solution!

Comment: Technically, this is more similar to `Result`'s `as_ref()`.